# Reading headers of previous request

Tags: php, http-headers

I came across a question which raised me some sort of curiosity. Is it possible to read custom headers sent in a different request?

Using [header_list()](https://www.php.net/headers_list) it's possible to read the headers sent, like the Content-type one. So, in the same request, this code:

```
<?php

header( 'My Header: My Value' );

print '<pre>'; 

print_r( headers_list() );
```

Would produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
    [1] => My Header: My Value
    [2] => Content-type: text/html
)
```

But what if I would like to get the **My Header** header in a different request, to a different URL maybe, after sending a Location header like this?

```
<?php

header( 'My Header: My Value' );

header( 'Location: test2.php' );
```

The print_r(), if used in **test2.php** lists the Content-type and the X-Powered-By, but it doesn't read the **My Header** header.

Comment: Redirects will not retain header information. You'll need to set the header again on the new page.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I thought, but even I studied a lot the HTTP Protocol (well, at least what is related to headers) in past, I had this curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the header list of a different request. The most obvious question would be: *which* different request?! There can be thousands of simultaneous "other" requests going on, so "another" request is a bit vague.

If you need to retain that information for later, store it somewhere, for example in the session.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I answered above, it was more a curiositity than a need.